Show the function is constant on its domain
Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in the unit disc such that $|f(z^2)| \geq |f(z)|$ for all $z$ in the disc. Prove that $f$ must be a constant in the disc.
My approach:
The only thing I could think of is the maximum principal. Since everything that's close to the origin is being mapped further to the origin by $f$. Let $z\in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$ then we construct the following sequence, $z_0=z$ and $z_n= z_{n-1}^2$, then it is clear that $|z_n|\to 0$ as $n\to 0$. And $|f(z_n)|\geq |f(z_{n-1})|\geq |f(z)|$ for all $n$. Hence $|f(0)|\geq |f(z)|$. $z$ was arbitrary so we conclude $|f(0)|\geq |f(z)|$ for all $z$ in the disc. Now, by maximum principal we have $f$ is constant.
Now, my concern is maximum principal requires $f$ to be continuous on the boundary, and I am not sure if I have that. I was also thinking maybe I could use Louville's theorem by post or pre comp the function. But that didnt work out.

I don't really understand your solution. Looks like $f$ is only defined in the open unit disc, so the number $z$ you defined doesn't really make sense. Anyway, try to show that $|f|$ has a maximum at the origin. To do so, indeed use sequences.

@Mark I see, but I would assume that achieving maximum at the origin and together with maximum principal I can conclude the function is constant.

@Mark could you let me know if my edited version seems reasonable? Thanks!

why not just apply max modulus to $\vert z \vert = \frac{1}{2}$? i.e. $\overline B\big(0, \frac{1}{2}\big)$ has an interior max with some $\vert w \vert = \frac{1}{4}$

@user8675309 Thank you! I never thought of tricks like that. Since that closure is inside the unit disc so I can definitely apply the max modulus to that. Now its clear!

Let $r\in (0,1)$ and $m=\max_{|z|=r} |f(z)|$ is attained at some $z_r$, with $|z_r|=r$. Then $z_r^2 \in B(z_r,r)$ and $|f(z_r^2)| = m$ and so $f$ is constant on $B(0,r)$.
